# Regular Expressions in finding LaTex directives in webpages with Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, latex, mathjax

I need to replace the LaTex directives in webpages. The LaTex directives are wraped in two '$' signs which are like $a^2+b^2=1$(an inline formula) or $$a^2+b^2=1$$(a block formula which will be displayed in a new line).
The question is now I want to use Javascript to replace thest directives with some pics(correspond to these directives), as the browsers itself are aparently not capable to display these formulas in a LaTex style. (see picture)[a^2+b^2=1](http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?a%5E2+b%5E2=1)How can I use Regular Expressions to do this? And I showed my work below, with some problems.
for inline formulas, I use:

```
var reg = /\$([^$]|(\\$))*\$(?=[^$])/mg
```

which means I want some text start with $ and after that whether it is 'not $' or it is '\$' or nothing, and end with '$' but after the end will not allowed the rise of $. Sounds good..
but for text like:$a^2\$b^2$ aparently, I wish it will displayed as (see picture) [a^2\$b^2](http://latex.codecogs.com/png.latex?a%5E2%5C%24b%5E2), but the truth is the regex replaces only part of it like '*replaced*b^2$'. I need some help~~

Comment: Your question aside, aren't you using Mathjax? http://www.mathjax.org/

Comment: Thank you for your advice. I haven't tried that package, but I have heard of it. In my application figures are prefered.

Comment: If you can, please try it. It's becoming a standard for this kind of stuff.

Comment: Shouldn't `(\\$)` be `(\\\$)`? Otherwise that $ will be treated as an end-of-string pattern.

Comment: I didn't catch you quite well. but I mean that between the $s there can be characters not $ OR there can be escaped $ like  \$  if it is really needed. why three \ is needed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following RegExp

```
/(\${1,2})((?:\\.|.)*)\1/
```

will match a LaTex block enclosed in single or double dollars. Note the use of the backreference \1 to match the opening tag.

If the LaTex blocks can extend ovver line boundaries then use

```
/(\${1,2})((?:\\.|[\s\S])*)\1/
```

To to a global replace within a string say `source`:

```
source.replace (/(\${1,2})((?:\\.|[\s\S])*)\1/g, function (m, tag, src) {
  // m is the entire match
  // tag is '$' or '$$' 
  // src is the internal text

  var rslt = ''; 

  // create what you want to appear in rslt.

  return rslt;
}
```

Comment: it works well in most situations, but suppose there were some $ signs in the formula, which is escaped by back slash \$, it will not lead to thew right result

Comment: I edit my answer. If you ask for the same outside the LaTex strings we will have to change things around a little. Til then....

Comment: this answer does not seem to support underscores, such as $\sum_{i=1}^n$.

Answer (score 1):

Following regex includes new lines (sometimes you have large formula and thus multiple lines):

`/(\${1,2})[^]*?[^\\]\1/gm`

And if you want to also match text outside delimiters:

`/(\${1,2})[^]*?[^\\]\1|[^\$]+\1/gm`

[Tests](https://regex101.com/r/4oL7ir/1)

Answer (score 0):

I don't know LaTex, but it looks like you are trying to do too much with one line of code.  Try a logical if else statement like the following:

```
if (var reg =/\$\$(.*?)\$\$/msg
    {block_formula=$1}

elsif (var reg=/\$(.*?)\$/msg
    {inline_formula=$1}
```

Which means "if reg starts and ends with $$, it's a block formula containing whatever is between the $$'s.  Else if reg starts and ends with $, it's an inline formula containing whatever is between the $'s."

Also, if it's only replacing part of the regex, be sure to put the -s flag to make sure it matches all instances.

Comment: not really, I specify the inline situation for example. I'm not trying to do both replacement in one line of code, the code above is specifically used in inline situation but it has something wrong if there is some escaped $ like '/$' in the string

Comment: OK, fixed that one. Now if you ask for the same outside the LaTex text we will have to go change things a little.

Comment: things does not always be so simple...I just want to find a match that will tolerant some escaped $ in the formular no matter what is it. Actually it may not have a = at all. Javascript does not support the so called _lookbehind_, or maybe I could use this to specify that the end $ should not have a backslash before, like (?<=[^\])$ which means before the end $ there shouldn't be a backslash. This works in perl.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know LaTex, but it looks like you are trying to do too much with one line of code.  Try a logical if else statement like the following:

if (var reg =/\$\$(.*?)\$\$/msg
    {block_formula=$1}

elsif (var reg=/\$(.*?)\$/msg
    {inline_formula=$1}

Which means "if reg starts and ends with $$, it's a block formula containing whatever is between the $$'s.  Else if reg starts and ends with $, it's an inline formula containing whatever is between the $'s."

Edit:  Try the regex more like /(\${1,2})(\S{2,10}=\d+)$1/  if formula always ends with = and numbers, to catch those \$'s in the middle.  If that doesn't work, give more examples so we can find a match.

Comment: things does not always be so simple...I just want to find a match that will tolerant some escaped $ in the formular no matter what is it. Actually it may not have a = at all. Javascript does not support the so called _lookbehind_, or maybe I could use this to specify that the end $ should not have a backslash before, like (?<=[^\])$ which means before the end $ there shouldn't be a backslash. This works in perl.